# Solving equation using Lambert $W$ function

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

Is someone able to walk me through solving the following inequality for x:

$$
a^{\frac{(k+1)(1-t)}{(k+t)(x+t)-(1-t)^2}} \cdot \left( \frac{k+t}{(1-t)(1+k)}-\frac{1}{1+x} \right) > b
$$

I assume I have to use the Lambert W function, omega function, or product logarithm?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have $a^{\frac{\something}{\something}} \cdot (\something}>b$

Comment: Yes! I just edited it.

Comment: @LiKa Maple gives the solutions in terms of the Lambert W function.

Comment: The problem can be simplified to: $$
a^{\frac{c}{1-c+x}} \cdot \left( \frac{1-c+x}{c(1+x)b} \right) > 1
$$  Yet I'm still not able to solve it. Is it even mathematically solvable?